# Removing child nodes on dynamic select

Tags: javascript, parent-child

I'm creating a dynamic selection form. Basically the user picks an option from the select and then depending on what option they chose it goes into a data object and then generates a new selection based on their previous answer. After they answer 3 questions regarding their vehicle choice it prints out their vehicle choice.

The problem I'm running into is having the ability to change a previous option on the fly. I'd like to have them be able to change a previous selection and it would remove the later selection

Ex. The user first selects Car, Ford and a selection for model is displayed. If the user went back and changed Car to Truck. I would like to remove Ford and the model selection. Here is the part of the code I have that holds the data and creates the new selections dynamically

```
    var data=new Object();// create a new data object to hold info


data['init']=['Car','Truck','SUV'];

data['Car']=['Audi','Dodge','Ford','Volkswagon'];
data['Audi']=['A4','TT','R8'];
data['Dodge']=['Charger','Challenger','Stealth'];
data['Ford']=['Focus','Fusion','Mustang'];
data['Volkswagon']=['Jetta','GTI','Beetle'];

data['Truck']=['Dodge Truck','Ford Truck','Toyota Truck'];
data['Dodge Truck'] = ['Ram-1500','Ram-2500','Ram-3500'];
data['Ford Truck'] = ['F-150','F-250','Ranger'];
data['Toyota Truck'] = ['Tundra','Tacoma'];

data['SUV']=['Dodge SUV','Ford SUV','Toyota SUV'];
data['Dodge SUV'] = ['Durango','Journey','Caliber'];
data['Ford SUV'] = ['Escape','Edge','Explorer'];
data['Toyota SUV'] = ['Rav4','Highlander','4runner'];

var hold = data['init'];//Sets data to 'init' by default

    var selectedArray = [];//This array holds the selected options (to be used to display the vehicle name)

    function init(){//call first to create the first select box and populate with 'init'        

    firstSelect = document.createElement('select');
    firstSelect.setAttribute("onChange","createSelect(this.value)");
    createSelect('init');       
}




//Main create function for select boxes
function createSelect(value){

    selectHold = value;//sets selectHold to the value of the selected item (this will be used for displaying    the name in disName)

    //This just prevents it from adding "Car, Truck or SUV to the selectedArray
    if(value != 'init' && value != 'Truck' && value != 'Car'  && value != 'SUV' && value != 'Select your vehicle options'){
        selectedArray.push(selectHold);
    }

    hold=data[value];// sets this holder to the value of the selected item for the if statement


    if(hold){   //just checks to see if hold exists

        var selEle = document.createElement('select');//creates new select element

        //gives selEle onchange function
        selEle.setAttribute("onChange","createSelect(this.value)");

        //Creates the "default" option. Forcing them to pick something.
        var defaultOpt = document.createElement('option');
        var vehInfo =  document.createTextNode("Select your vehicle options");
        defaultOpt.appendChild(vehInfo);
        selEle.appendChild(defaultOpt);

        //Populates the options and adds it to the document
        for(var i = 0, l = hold.length; i < l; i++){
            var newOpt = document.createElement('option');
            newOpt.appendChild(document.createTextNode( hold[i]));
            newOpt.setAttribute('value',hold[i]);
            selEle.appendChild(newOpt);
        }


        //put select on the page
        document.getElementById('top-container').appendChild(selEle);
        }

    else{       //if not, then put out final form
        disName(selectHold,selectedArray);//call disName function an dpass it the value of selectHold   

        }

}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="top-container">
    <h1>Awesome<br/>
    Car<br/>
    Picker</h1>


    </div>
    <div id="middle-container">
<h2>Your vechle choice:</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom-container">
    <div id="mail-form">
    <form name='mail-form'>

    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" autofocus>

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email">

    <label>Credit Card number</label>
    <input name="cc">

    <input id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="validate()">

    </form>
    </div>

    </div>

    <body>
```

What I'm thinking is to check the to see if the selection is the lastChild of the parent node (top container). and if it is not then delete the child of that until it's at the point where it's only the selection that was changed and any selection that fell before it.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `createSelect` function, assign an ID to the new element using something like `selEle.id = 'newID';`.

Before calling the `createSelect` function, check to see if the new element exists and if so, remove it:

```
if (document.getElementById('newID'))
    document.getElementById('top-container').removeChild(document.getElementById('newID'));
```

Comment: If I assigned an id in the 'createSelect' function wouldn't that give each new select an Id? Wouldn't that remove all the selects that had that Id?

Comment: Perhaps create another parameter for the `createSelect` function to pass in an ID to use, like `selModel`, `selMake`, `selYear`, etc...